# Unable to install jdk1.8.0_65 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java, jdk

I've created the /usr/lib/java directory and moved the jdk directory in it.
but while using the following commands, i'm not getting any output(not even an error):

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_65/bin/java" 1

sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_65/bin/javac" 1

sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_65/bin/javaws" 1
```

I rather continued the further process and updated the JAVA_HOME in ~/.bashrc file. Eventually the output for 'java -version' was:

```
bash: /usr/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

I checked /usr/bin/java and didn't find the expected java directory there:

```
bash: cd: /usr/bin/java: Not a directory
```

please help asap!

Comment: Which java are you trying to install Oracle or OpenJDK?

Comment: oracle java 8: jdk1.8.0_65

Comment: Why the outdated version?

Comment: i had downloaded it a few days ago, didn't realize about the 8u71! Does that really make a difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to use ppa. Run in terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

That will install the latest Oracle JDK.